# Hazelcast client: how to set the port

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a hazelcast cluster running and want to connect a client to it.

The hazelcast cluster is running on the default port 5701. I know this and can even mandate it in the server configuration.

The client however starts scanning a random set of ports sometimes trying more than 10 ports before finally attempting 5701 at which point it succeeds.

This is however an excruciatingly slow process.

Is there a way to tell the client that it should first try port 5701?

Note that I am configuring the client programmatically. Does anyone have any pointers?

**UPDATE**: note that I'm using the aws cluster detection meaning I can't simply hardcode the addresses with the ports included.

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
ClientAwsConfig awsConfig = new ClientAwsConfig();
awsConfig.setEnabled(true);
awsConfig.setTagKey(getConfig().getAmazonTagKey());
awsConfig.setTagValue(getConfig().getAmazonTagValue());
awsConfig.setRegion(getConfig().getAmazonRegion());
config.getNetworkConfig().setAwsConfig(awsConfig);
client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
```

Comment: Can you add client's configuration? especially `ClientNetworkConfig`

Comment: @mdogan I added the configuration

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following worked:

```
awsConfig.setProperty("hz-port", "5701");
```